# Не могу импортировать модуль. [django]

Tags: python, django

Проблема во вложении. Создал приложение [startapp], добавил функцию в views, теперь не могу импортировать ее в urls
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

`from ..horoscope import views` поменяйте на `from .horoscope import views`

На будущее, прикладывайте код, а не скриншоты.

Comment: Ошибка. И сразу же вопрос:     1) . -текущая директория
                                                     2).. - директория выше

Comment: Вы пишите, что из текущей директории (horoscope), нужно импортировать views, НО этого нельзя сделать. Ведь мы находимся в my_page